# Javascript locating element By Name failing in New Relic monitor

Tags: javascript, monitoring, newrelic, scriptedbrowser

This is a javascript snippet written in New Relic monitor which is trying to locate element from a webpage based on its name or xpath.

```
return $browser.findElement($driver.By.name('USER')).then(function(element){
  return element.sendKeys("********").then(function(){ 
    return $browser.findElement($driver.By.name('PASSWORD')).then(function(element){
      return element.sendKeys("********");}).then(function(){
        return $browser.waitForAndFindElement($driver.By.name("Submit")).then(function(element){
          element.click();
          $browser.sleep(5000);
        });
      })
    })
  })
```

However during validation this is the error thrown..

> NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name="USER"]"}

[image: error]

Comment: If the screenshot is where the script is failing, it's not loading the page. Have you solved loading the page first?